# E-commerce platforms APIs

Tags: e-commerce

I am creating an application for my client and I need to connect to E-commerce platforms like Flipkart, Amazon, Meesho, Tata Cliq, Jio Mart, Shopsy via APIs.

I found an API for Flipkart and Amazon, but could not be able to find for other platforms which are Meesho, Tata Cliq, Jio Mart, Shopsy. Is anyone have experience or have knowledge of it who can help me to get a reference?

I want to connect with products and orders for each platforms for that particular seller only.